# What are ACEs called for system vs. domain users and groups?

Tags: windows, access-control-list

What terminology is used for system ACEs (local accounts / groups), and what terminology is used for domain ACEs (domain accounts / groups)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such distinction. Your usage of the terms "system ACEs" vs. "domain ACEs" is misleading.

An ACE is an element in an ACL. An ACL may have many ACEs in it, and those ACEs may apply to trustees from various different authorities, be it a local user account, or a security principal from this Active Directory domain, or a security principal from another domain. The same ACL may even contain a mixture of security principals from the aforementioned authorities, but that still never changes the "terminology" or the name used. It's just an ACL.

There are two types of ACLs on most types of objects in Windows:

- Discretionary Access Control List (DACL.) This is what people think of when they think of ACLs, usually.
- System Access Control List (SACL.) This type of ACL tells Windows which types of operations by which users shall be logged to the Security event log. It's used for auditing access attempts, etc.

That's it. That's all there is. No special names for "local vs. domain."